# Testing AJAX in Django

Tags: django, ajax, testing

I want to test an AJAX call in my Django app.

What is does is adding a product to a favorite list. But I can't find a way to test it.

My views.py:

```
def add(request):
    data = {'success': False} 
    if request.method=='POST':
        product = request.POST.get('product')
        user = request.user       
        splitted = product.split(' ')
        sub_product = Product.objects.get(pk=(splitted[1]))
        original_product = Product.objects.get(pk=(splitted[0]))       
        p = SavedProduct(username= user, sub_product=sub_product, original_product = original_product)
        p.save()        
        data['success'] = True
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

My html:

```
<form class="add_btn" method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
 <button class='added btn' value= '{{product.id }} {{ sub_product.id }}' ><i class=' fas fa-save'></i></button
```

My AJAX:

```
$(".row").on('click', ".added", function(event) {
    let addedBtn = $(this);
    console.log(addedBtn)
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    var product = $(this).val();    
    console.log(product)   
    var url = '/finder/add/';   
    $.ajax({        
        url: url,        
        type: "POST",
        data:{
            'product': product,            
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(data) {
          if (data['success'])            
          addedBtn.hide();             
        }
    }); 
});
```

The problem is that I pass `'{{product.id }} {{ sub_product.id }}'` into my views.

My test so far:

```
class Test_add_delete(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        self.user= User.objects.create(username="Toto", email="toto@gmail.com")

        self.prod = Product.objects.create(
            name=['gazpacho'],
            brand=['alvalle'],
            )

        self.prod_2 = Product.objects.create(
            name=['belvita'],
            brand=['belvita', 'lu', 'mondelez'],
            )

    def test_add(self):
        old_saved_products = SavedProduct.objects.count()      
        user = self.user.id
        original_product = self.prod.id
        sub_product = self.prod_2.id
        response = self.client.post(reverse('finder:add', args=(user,))), {
        'product': original_product, sub,product })   
        new_saved_products = SavedProducts.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(new_saved_products, old_saved_products + 1)
```

My test is not running and I get a SyntaxError  `'product': original_product, sub_product`. I know it's not the proper way to write it but my AJAX send the two ids with a space in between to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is test if the data was actually saved, instead of just returning `data['success'] = True` you can return the whole entire new object... That way you can get back the item you just created from your API, and see all the other fields that may have been auto-gen (ie date_created and so on). That's a common thing you'll see across many APIs. 
Another way to test this on a Django level is just to use python debugger
`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` right before your return and you can just see what `p` is.
The `set_trace()` will stop python and give you access to the code scope from the command line. So just type 'l' to see where you are, and type(and hit enter) anything else that's defined, ie `p` which will show you what `p` is. You can also type h for the help menue and read the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

Comment: Problem is I can't find a way yo pass all the datas into AJAX.

Comment: That's a JQuery question. I don't think I can help too much with that. But you can still use PDB to see if your data is coming in via the request.